# how back to old version of Prisma in npm. Or remove one totally

Tags: prisma, npm-package

Can not remove Prisma in Mac Ventura
`npm uninstall -g prisma` not giving result
`npm v prisma` showing what Prisma still in system

```
 ~/ npm v prisma
prisma@4.16.2 | Apache-2.0 | deps: 1 | versions: 5256
Prisma is an open-source database toolkit. It includes a JavaScript/TypeScript ORM for Node.js, migrations and a modern GUI to view and edit the data in your database. You can use Prisma in new projects or add it to an existing one.
https://www.prisma.io

keywords: orm, prisma2, prisma, cli, database, sql, postgresql, mysql, sqlite, mariadb, mssql, typescript, query-builder

bin: prisma, prisma2

dist
.tarball: https://registry.npmjs.org/prisma/-/prisma-4.16.2.tgz
.shasum: 469e0a0991c6ae5bcde289401726bb012253339e
.integrity: sha512-SYCsBvDf0/7XSJyf2cHTLjLeTLVXYfqp7pG5eEVafFLeT0u/hLFz/9W196nDRGUOo1JfPatAEb+uEnTQImQC1g==
.unpackedSize: 13.8 MB

dependencies:
@prisma/engines: 4.16.2

dist-tags:
dev: 4.17.0-dev.61                                                    integration: 4.17.0-integration-cockroachdb-with-postgres-provider.2  latest: 4.16.2                                                        patch-dev: 4.16.2-dev.4

published 6 days ago by prismabot <bot@prisma.io>
```

Totally Prisma removing